# I want to use my variables in one method in another method

Tags: python, variables, return

I want to use the variables in my "Person Builder" function in the JSON I will create, but I cannot pull variables like "PersonID" in the "jsonAPI" function. How do I solve this problem?

My Code :

```py
def PersonBuilder():
        PersonID = 1
        PersonName = "Behzat"
        PersonSurname = "Çözer"
        PersonCompany = "EGM"
        PersonTitle = "Başkomiser"
        return {'PersonID': PersonID,'PersonName': PersonName, 'PersonSurname': PersonSurname,'PersonCompany': PersonCompany, 'PersonTitle': PersonTitle}

def PhoneNumberBuilder():
        PhoneID = 1
        PhoneCountry = "Turkey"
        PhoneOperator = "TR XXXXXX"
        PhoneNumber = "+905XXXXXXXX"
        return {'PhoneID': PhoneID,'PhoneCountry': PhoneCountry, 'PhoneOperator': PhoneOperator,'PhoneNumber': PhoneNumber}

def jsonAPI():

    myjson3 = {  
        "Person":{ 
            'PersonID' : PersonID,
            'PersonName' : PersonName,
            'PersonSurname': PersonSurname,
            'PersonCompany': PersonCompany,
            'PersonTitle': PersonTitle,
            'PhoneID':PhoneID,
            'PhoneCountry': PhoneCountry,
            'PhoneOperator':PhoneOperator,
            'PhoneNumber':PhoneNumber
            }
    }

    out_file = open("myfile.json", "w") 
    json.dump(myjson3, out_file, indent = 6)
    jsonify(myjson3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: "I cannot pull variables like "PersonID" in the "jsonAPI" function." Why can't you? Just call it and use the value it returns.... `myjson3 = {"Person": {**PersonBuilder(), **PhoneNumberBuilder()}}` (or more verbose approaches storing returns to names and extracting). There's no reason for the functions to exist, but it works. I feel like you don't understand the basics of programming (not Python specifically, but programming in general) here, so I'm going to *strongly* recommend you take actual classes to learn; you can't learn programming from scratch, a question at a time, on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're not even calling those functions in the first place. How can you use their variables?

Comment: @BehzatÇ.: You cannot learn to program by "doing projects" when you don't know the basics at all. At best you'll stumble along getting things right after doing 10x the necessary work, producing bad results and never knowing there were better solutions. Once you have a sufficient grounding, you can "learn by doing", but you need to know the basics of functions, conditionals, data structure usage, etc., and the only practical way to learn that is a structured class or in-depth tutorial, you can't just throw code at things until it works, picking up *everything* along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions return dictionaries. You can combine these two dictionaries to get the `Person` dictionary in `myjson3`.

```
def jsonAPI():
    myjson3 = {
        "Person": PersonBuilder() | PhoneNumberBuilder()
    }
    with open("myfile.json", "w") as out_file:
        json.dump(myjson3, out_file, index = 6)
        jsonify(myjson3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the methods and use the values they return.

```
def jsonAPI():

    myjson3 = PersonBuilder() | PhoneNumberBuilder()

    # ... etc
```